# How to launch WhatsApp on Android using Appium

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

while launch WhatsApp using App-package and App-Activity
capabilities it loads like first time after installation and needed new registration.

Am i missing something?
Is that known issue in Whats-App?

Thanks

Comment: I use the following capabilities: PlatformName="Android" PlatformVersion="6.0.1" DeviceName="GS6" AppPackage="com.whatsapp" AppActivity="com.whatsapp.Main"

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer :)
When appium launch the app it by default reset the app, in my case its bad.
So i added to my desired capabilities:
        desired_caps['noReset'] = true
        desired_caps['fullReset'] = false
In that case appium will not reset the app and just open it.